# Script run in background without waiting for input

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

so I managed to my script work even when when popup is closed but the script doesnt react on button it keeps refreshing the site, could you guys help me and tell me what is wrong in this background.js?
I have separate content.js and html file.

```
function startref() {

    let intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (arrayOfTabs) {
            var code = 'window.location.reload();';
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(arrayOfTabs[0].id, { code: code });


        });

    }, 3000);
    localStorage.setItem('refresh', intervalId);
}


function stop() {
    const intervalId = localStorage.getItem("refresh");
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var sta = document.getElementById("startbtn");
    var sto = document.getElementById("stopbtn");
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        sta.addEventListener('click', startref);

    });


    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        sto.addEventListener('click', stop);

    });
    if (localStorage.getItem("refresh")) {
        startref();
        

    }
    
};
```

Comment: Do you have `refresh` in your localStorage ? Because according to your code, if `refresh` exist in the localStorage on page load, then the `startref()` function will be called.

Comment: ```refresh``` is created by ```startref()``` and should be deleted with ```stop()```. When this script is inside ```content.js``` it works fine but cant work when popup is closed. When this script is in ```background.js``` it works in background but buttons doesn't work so i can't turn refreshing off\